# convert GLubyte* to GLuint* for alpha texturing Opengl 3.0 / c++ / Win32

Tags: c++, opengl, alpha

My goal here is to make a texture's pixel value 100% transparent if it matches a set RGB color exactly. My program uses 24-bit .bmp images which I know do not contain a fourth channel (besides the padding), so Ive been trying to come up with a good way to facilitate adding an alpha channel to perform basic transparency.

I understand how to compute the actual alpha value and set the blending functions correctly, but I hit a roadblock when I tried to add a fourth value to a GLubyte RGB triple, leading me to believe that that format simply doesn't support alpha. So i had an idea to manually convert the texture data from bytes to 32-bit unsigned ints, but im having trouble with the execution. It seems to me (from looking at books) that the internal pixel format GL_UNSIGNED_INT will take four 32-bit integers per pixel, but my program won't launch when I convert the bytes by clamping the 0.0-1.0 byte values to the max range of an unsigned int.

I dont want the answer given to me, but I would really appreciate a push in the right direction. Am i on the right track converting to 4 ints per pixel, or is there possibly a way to make alpha work with byte data that im overlooking? Ive considered using the GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8888 format but I want to avoid bit-shifting if at all possible.

Comment: What problem did you have when trying to add the alpha in `GLubyte` format? There really shouldn't be anything to it. You simply have 4 bytes per texel, where you had 3 bytes per texel before, and specify the format as RGBA instead of RGB.

Answer (score 3):

`GL_UNSIGNED_INT` is not the *"internal pixel format"*. That is actually the pixel transfer data type.

For many years, internal formats in GL were a bit of an enigma, you had to request the number of components but not much else. These days (GL3+) you have to use explicitly sized internal formats such as `GL_RGB8` and that leaves most of the guesswork out. You can still assume, however, that `GL_RGB8` is going to be padded with an extra 8-bits by the driver so that each color begins on a power-of-two boundary. `GL_RGB8` therefore has the same storage requirements as `GL_RGBA8` and the only difference between the two is that `GL_RGB8` has all opaque pixels.

When you use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` as your data type for pixel transfer, that means that GL is going to interpret your input image data as having 32-bits (unsigned) per-color component (12-bytes per-pixel). You do not want that, you currently have 3 unsigned 8-bit components per-pixel and thus `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is appropriate (3-bytes per-pixel). *The addition of a 4<sup>th</sup> component does not change the size of the individual components.*

Regarding `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`, that is actually slightly different than `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` if you are trying to upload an RGBA image. It is what is known as a packed data type; 4 components are packed into the same footprint as a `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` and each component is 8-bits. There also exists `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV`, which is a lot more useful - it tells GL to reverse the color components during pixel transfer and is something you cannot do if you just specify `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as the data type. `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8[_REV]` resolves CPU byte order issues, and on a little-endian CPU `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` is equivalent to `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

---

Keep in mind that GL expects each row of your image to begin on a 4-byte boundary.

If you have a 24-bit per-pixel image with a width that is not divisible by 4, then your data will be misaligned and GL will incorrectly unpack it. To work around that you can set the unpack alignment to **1**-byte (default is **4**) like so:

```
glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

*The .bmp file format already pads the end of each row to satisfy 4-byte alignment, this is just something I wanted to point out for completeness.*

Comment: As for the rest of your question, you are looking for color key transparency. You can either pre-process your data to insert the alpha component, or you can do it with a fragment shader. I would personally pre-process the data, because `RGB` images are padded on the GPU to `RGBA` anyway so you might as well use that otherwise wasted memory.

Comment: At least on little endian architectures, which are prevalent these days, I believe it's `8_8_8_8_REV` that is equivalent to `BYTE`. `8_8_8_8` is the one that byte swaps.

Comment: If you look at the spec (e.g. page 131 in the 3.3 spec), the 1st component is in bits 0-7 for the `_REV` format. That's also the 1st byte for `UNSIGNED_BYTE` if the host format is little endian. Try it on any Intel machine, and you'll find that `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` produce the same result.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Ah, yes. You are correct, I was thinking of something else. It is the multi-byte component formats (e.g. `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`) that are affected by `GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be straight forward with no hacks required. There are 2 ways to achieve what you need. The fist solution is to simply load your bmp as normal RGB data, then allocate a new buffer with extra 30% size for the alpha channel and for every 3 bytes you copy over, add a byte representing the alpha value you want. Then while uploading to OpenGL device, declare it is GL_RGBA instead of GL_RGB, while keeping the format as GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE. This way you convert your data from 3 channels to 4 channels at load time. The second solution is to perform fragment discard in fragment shader, because discarding is the same as 100% transparent. Since you know which color you want to discard, you can pass those rgb values to the shader using uniform or any other means, the fragment shader can then check and discard accordingly. You don't even have to worry about the alpha channel in this solution.